# extract clipping path info from jpg "saved with clipping path" in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, photoshop

Hi if I have jpg's saved with clipping path, how do I get that info from c#?

This bit of code can give me some metadata, but I think the clipping path info is (photoshop?) proprietary extension? How can I read it ?

```
BitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(new FileStream(filespec, FileMode.Open), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
BitmapMetadata meta = (BitmapMetadata)decoder.Frames[0].Metadata;
return meta.Keywords.ToArray<string>();
```

Comment: jpegs don't have clipping paths... Photoshop psd files can contain such information so you would need specs from Adobe in order to get that information from a Photoshop file...

Comment: no Photoshop saves the metadata in the jpg - if you open a jpg with a clipping path in photoshop you'll see it ( even without the original psd file )

Comment: JPGs can contain a clipping path, run 'identify.exe -verbose' from ImageMagick http://www.imagemagick.org on the JPG, you'll see the path in the output.  If you can't find c# code you could always launch identify.exe and process the output.

Comment: Did you find an answer? If so, please share.